# Is it possible to have multiple potential values for a variable in java

Tags: java, if-statement, variables

This is a portion of my code, I'd like a variable be assigned a certain rate depending on the different custid number. I'm seeing a duplicate local variable error, is there anyway to get around this?

```
if(custid<=100 && custid>=1) {
        double disc = .15;
    }
    else if(custid<=250 && custid>=101) {
        double disc = .18;
    }
    else if(custid<=500 && custid>=251) {
        double disc = .23;
    }
    else if(custid<=1000 && custid>=501) {
        double disc = .28;
    } 
    else if(custid>=1001) {
        double disc = .32;
    } 

    if(bill>=1000) {
        System.out.println(bill*disc);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your variable before conditions. Then you only have to assign value to this variable:

```
    double disc = 0;

    if(custid<=100 && custid>=1) {
        disc = .15;
    }
    else if(custid<=250 && custid>=101) {
        disc = .18;
    }
    else if(custid<=500 && custid>=251) {
        disc = .23;
    }
    else if(custid<=1000 && custid>=501) {
        disc = .28;
    } 
    else if(custid>=1001) {
        disc = .32;
    } 

    if(bill>=1000) {
        System.out.println(bill*disc);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to declare the variable data type once, as you are declaring it multiple times whilst assigning it, hence the duplicate local variable error. Declare your variable once before the conditions to allow it to be reassignable in your conditions.

Try this:

```
double disc = 0;

if(custid<=100 && custid>=1) {
    disc = .15;
}
else if(custid<=250 && custid>=101) {
    disc = .18;
}
else if(custid<=500 && custid>=251) {
    disc = .23;
}
else if(custid<=1000 && custid>=501) {
    disc = .28;
} 
else if(custid>=1001) {
    disc = .32;
}
```